# Issue in finding tag with a certain attribute - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, tags, beautifulsoup

I have the following code, in Python 2.7, that reads an HTML and then tries to find a tag with certain attribute as follows:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read())
tmp = soup.findAll("ul", {"id" : "zg_browseRoot"})
```

But when I debug the code `tmp` is empty. If I look at the `soup` I see this:

```
...
  <ul id="zg_browseRoot">
    <li> 

     <span class="zg_selected"> Any Department</span>
    </li> 

<ul>
      <li><a href='http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances'>Appliances</a></li>
      <li><a href='http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps'>Appstore for Android</a></li>
      <li><a href='http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Arts-Crafts-Sewing/zgbs/arts-crafts'>Arts, Crafts & Sewing</a></li>
...
      <li><a href='http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Watches/zgbs/watches'>Watches</a></li>
</ul>

  </li></ul>
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE 1** I tested the code on another machine and it works fine. Has anybody seen something like this? Is there anything wrong on my Python or the libraries?

Comment: I don't know who is behaving strangely, but running above codes (+ `print tmp`) 4 times gave me three different kind of output : http://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Z7y.png

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: Yes, 2.7.9 if remember correctly (writing on phone right now)

Comment: So you used the exact code above and just added `print tmp` and got the results?

Comment: Yup, copy pasted exact code above, removed 'dots' line, added print tmp after the last line